# Router change file for static files

Tags: python, python-2.7, tornado

I have routers/handlers in Tornado app like

```
    handlers = [
        (r"/", BaseHandler),
        (r"/salary/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$", BaseHandler),
        (r"/salary/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$", BaseHandler),
    ]
```

and static files inside settings like

```
        static_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static"),
```

and when I call web page with url

`/salary/99` it works fine

but when I call like

`/salary/99/33`  it doesn't work (doesn't work for any for router  r"/salary/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$"). Doesn't work means doesn't load css and js => change static files path to `/salary/static....`  instead of `/static...`)
How adds this salary from router to static path, how to avoid this ?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is instruct Tornado how to serve static files. Read the first paragraphs of http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/branch2.4/web.html#application-configuration, you will find that you will either define a `tornado.web.StaticFileHandler` or set `static_path`.